# Studying the function $f(x) = x^4-6x^2$ using derivatives: minima, maxima, inflection, concavity

Tags: calculus, derivatives

(I know this is my second question today, but I'm explaining what I'm doing so I hope it's okay)

Consider the graph of $f(x) = x^4-6x^2$.

> a) Find the relative maxima and minima (both x and y coordinates).

I actually forgot how to do this.. not the point of my question though.

> b) Find the coordinates of the point(s) of inflection.

So for this, you take the derivative of the derivative, correct?

$f'(x) = 4x^3-12x$

$f''(x) = 12x^2-12.$

$f''(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow 12x^2 = 12 \Leftrightarrow x = -1, 1.$

So the points are $(-1,5)$ and $(1,5)$ (y coordinate from plugging back into the original)?

> c) Determine the interval(s) on which the function is increasing.

When I set the derivative equal to zero to find the potential turning points, I get 0, rad 3, and negative rad 3. Forgot what to do from here. Not important.

> d) Determine the interval(s) on which the function is concave up.

I get $(-\infty,-1) \cup (1,\infty)$

*Answer only what you want. Any help is appreciated!

Source: http://online.math.uh.edu/apcalculus/exams/AB_SECTION_II_version_1.pdf - #4

Comment: well, now you should either write your own answer or mark an answer as the correct one (:

Answer (score 1):

a) Min/Max: calculate the derivative of the function and equal it to zero to find the x-coordinate of the extreme points of the function. Then calculate the second derivative and evaluate it on these extreme values of $x$. If the 2nd derivative is positive, then the slope of the tangent is growing and thus we have a minimum at $(x, f(x))$. if the 2nd derivative is negative; we have a maximum $(x, f(x))$

b) That's right.

c) function opens up when $f''(x)>0$

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you mean for part a. I set the first derivative equal to zero. I got 0, -rad3, and rad3. Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Always remember that "the value of the derivative at a given point is the value of the slope of the tangent line touching that point" or in other words: "the value of the derivative is the rate of change of our function". So, calculate the second derivative $f''$ and exaluate $f''(0)$, $f''(-rad3)$, and $f''(rad3)$. Then continue reading above: "if the 2nd ..."

Answer (score -1):

after that find $f'(x)=0$ here you get two points.

Then evaluate these two points in $f''(x)$ for each of these two points.

then you get one negative -ve(local maximum),put put this value in f(x).

then other you will get +ve positive (local minimum) value after putting in f''(x). put this value in f(x).

Note: put the x-values in f(x), not that positive and negative value.